# Wrong Position Is Returned

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

This is the strangest thing. I have an Arraylist being called into an imageview. The image returned is in the position it should be when the image is clicked but when I use a Log, the image returned is the next image, instead of the image in the position.

```
 Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(mImages.get(position))
                .noCache()
                .progressBar(progressBar)

                .progressHandler(new ProgressCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(long downloaded, long total) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }


                })

                .intoImageView(imageView)
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<ImageView>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, ImageView imageView) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
                });
```

And the log right underneath:

```
        Log.d("position of url  = ", (mImages.get(position));
```

This is all placed in a PagerAdapter with the position of the viewpager sourced from a gridview. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

```
position=viewPager.getCurrentItem();
```

and it works fine now!